# force the text to start in the second column in each chapter of a two-column document

Tags: two-column, scrbook

I have tried without success to force the text to start automatically in the second column of each chapter including in the bibliography

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,spanish,10pt, letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\starthalfpage}{\quad \\[50em]}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\starthalfpage
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]\cite{1}

\bibliographystyle{pain}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (internal) command `\@topnewpage` should be the best place to insert some extra formatting commands (lacking an official "hook" for such insertion). That will apply to several similar places: after `\maketitle` and `\part`, as well as after `\chapter` -- whether explicit or hiding in the bibliography.  Scrbook uses a redefined version of `\@topnewpage` which ends with a command `\@at@twocolumnfalse`, so target that.

```
\newcommand{\starthalfpage}{\par\vspace*{\fill}\break}

\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\@at@twocolumnfalse{\starthalfpage}
\makeatother
```

Don't use `\starthalfpage` explicitly in the document unless you are really forced to.